# How to generate a new log file in python every time the application runs or log size reaches maximum or date is changed?

Tags: python, logging

I want to achieve two things while configuring my log file in python:

1. Generate a new logging file **every time either of the following occurs**:

   - A new instance of the application is invoked i.e. every time the application is run, or
   - The size of the log reaches max value (lets say 2000 bytes), or
   - The Date is changed in middle of the application running (the case when application starts before midnight and ends after it)
2. The log file name should append the parameters passed to it by the calling function. For e.g. if my log file is `abc.log` and my input parameters are (which will change everytime) `'i-y'` , then log file name should be `abc_i-y.log`.

Till now I am only able to generate a new log file with each run of the application but unable to roll over based on size or date change. The code that I am using is:

```
import logging.handlers
import time
import os
from pro_path import ROOT_DIR

filename = "Pro/project.log"
logger = logging.getLogger('Pro')

fh = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename, backupCount=10)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s: %(module)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)

logfile = (os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, filename))
roll_over = os.path.isfile(logfile)

if roll_over:
    logger.debug('\n---\nLog closed at %s.\n---\n' % time.asctime())
    fh.doRollover()

logger.debug('\n---\nLog started at %s.\n---\n' % time.asctime())

self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

I tried specifying maxBytes parameter inside RotatingFileHandler but got error.

I am just starting out in python so I am not even sure if all 3 in point 1 can be achieved together because all I know is that you can rollover either on size or on date.

Any help on how to tweak this code to achieve both points 1 & 2 will be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: I tried specifying maxBytes parameter inside RotatingFileHandler but got error.

what's error?

Comment: `@saul` The error got resolved now :)) Can you help me with point 1c and 2?